# What loop should I use to end rock paper scissor program?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

I need to make my rock paper scissor program to run as a loop untill user puts in a finishing input `avslutt`. What loop type should I use and where should I put it?

```
//Stein saks papir
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random;
public class oppgave3{
  public static void main (String[]args){
    //setter muligheten for 
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in);
    int spillerValg = 0;
    int poengS=0;
    int poengD=0;
    int uavgjort=0;

    //forklarer bruker fremgangsmåte

    System.out.println("Skriv stein, saks, papir eller avslutt:");
    String spiller = tastatur.nextLine();

   //omgjør brukerinput til tallverdier for å lettere sammenligne
       if(spiller.equals("stein")){
         spillerValg = 0;
       }
       if (spiller.equals("saks")) {
         spillerValg = 1;
       }
       if (spiller.equals("papir")) {
          spillerValg = 2;
       }
        if(spiller.equals("avslutt")){
          spillerValg = 3;
  }





    int dataValg = rand.nextInt(3);




    if(spillerValg <= 3){ 
          if (spillerValg == dataValg){
      System.out.println("Begge valgte samme!");
      System.out.println("Uavgjort");
        uavgjort++;

}
     else if (dataValg == 0 && spillerValg == 1){
      System.out.println("Spillervalg: Saks");
      System.out.println("Datavalg: Stein");
      System.out.println("Data vant!");
         poengD++;
    }
     else if(dataValg == 0 && spillerValg == 2){
      System.out.println("Spillervalg: Papir");
      System.out.println("Datavalg: Stein");
      System.out.println("Du vant!");
           poengS++;
  }
      else if(dataValg == 1 && spillerValg == 0){
       System.out.println("Spillervalg: Stein");
       System.out.println("Datavalg: Saks");
       System.out.println("Du vant!");                 //0=stein 1= saks 2=papir
           poengS++;
}
     else if(dataValg == 1 && spillerValg == 2){
      System.out.println("Spillervalg: Papir");
      System.out.println("Datavalg: Saks");
      System.out.println("Data vant!");
          poengD++;
}
     else if(dataValg == 2 && spillerValg == 0){
      System.out.println("Spillervalg: Stein");
      System.out.println("Datavalg: Papir");
      System.out.println("Data vant!");
         poengD++;
}
     else if(dataValg == 2 && spillerValg == 1){
      System.out.println("Spillervalg: Saks");
      System.out.println("Datavalg: Papir");
      System.out.println("Du vant!");
        poengS++;
  }

    }
  if (spillerValg == 3);
    System.out.println("Spill avsluttet");
    System.out.println("Uavgjort "+uavgjort+" ganger");
    System.out.println("Du vant "+poengS+ " ganger");
    System.out.println("Data vant "+poengD+" ganger");




    tastatur.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a function to model one game. Then the loop choice will become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide what loop to use.

A for loop does not sound like the right choice, since you don't know how many iterations you want to do when you start. So it should either be a while or a do-while.

You use a do-while when you always want to loop at least once. A common situation is that you do not have a value for the condition until you have performed the operation once. In your case, that is sort of the case (you don't know if the user entered `avslutt` until you asked), but you could use both a while and a do-while.

As this looks a little bit like homework, I will give you a rough outline in pseudo code.

First, as a do-while:

```
do
    x = user input
    if x <> "avslutt"
        play the game
loop while x <> "avslutt"
```

Second, as a while:

```
x = user input
while x <> "avslutt"
    play the game
    x = user input
```

Bathshebas suggestion to put the actual game in a function, and call it inside the loop is a good one. Whenever you have long code inside a loop, you should consider that.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I managed to get it working with a do while statement. However i didn't get the user input to work without getting a "duplicate variable" error in the "while"-statement. I would appreciate a pointer towards how i could write that into the code!

Comment: You declare the same variable every time you loop. I guess it is the variable `spiller`? I guess you have `string spiller = tastatur...` inside the loop? The `string` keyword means that you declare the variable, and you can only do that once. Put `string spiller;` outside the loop to declare it once. Then inside the loop, you can freely change the value as many times as you like by using `spiller = tastatur...` without the `string` keyword at the beginning of the line.

Comment: yes, that's the one! of course, remembered now that you said it^^ so much to get my head around when it comes to java. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ramboleif Glad it worked! Feel free to upvote or mark this answer as accepted if you think it was helpful.